# Beginner with kali, I want to install bless and I get and error that 'no gmcs C# compiler found'

Tags: c#, mono

So I tried to install gmcs C# compiler

```
sudo apt-get install mono-gmcs
```

but I get the next error and I do not know what to do from here on now:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
>   been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
>   resolve the situation: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   mono-gmcs : Depends: mono-mcs (= 3.12.1-0xamarin1) but
>   4.2.1.102+dfsg2-5 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 1):

> mono-gmcs : Depends: mono-mcs (= 3.12.1-0xamarin1) but 4.2.1.102

Mono's `gmcs` is deprecated in the latest versions and you should be targeting to use `mcs` (or Roslyn's `csc` in the near future).

Since Kali Linux is a Debain-based distribution:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

[#Usage](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#usage)

The package `mono-devel` should be installed to compile code.

The package `mono-complete` should be installed to install everything - this should cover most cases of “assembly not found” errors.

The package `referenceassemblies-pcl` should be installed for PCL compilation support - this will resolve most cases of “Framework not installed: .NETPortable” errors during software compilation.

The package `ca-certificates-mono` should be installed to get SSL certificates for HTTPS connections. Install this package if you run into trouble making HTTPS connections.

[APT package setup](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives)